# changing coefficient to obtain a nonsingular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a problem , I started thinking about but no result yet

Let $A$ be a matrix over $M_n(R)$ .How much at minimum we must change coefficients of $A$ to obtain an inverible matrix ?

Sorry if my english is bad , I will write it in french :

Soit A une matrice de $M_n(R)$. Combien faut-il au minimum modifier de coefficients de $A$ pour que la matrice devienne inversible ?

Comment: How do you measure minimum change in coefficients?

Comment: Is $R$ any ring? Or is it just the field of real numbers? Besides, you should make assumptions on the matrix $A$, if $A$ is already invertible, there is nothing to do. Maybe you want to ask, if the entries of $A$ are random variables following a given joint probability distribution, what is the esperance of the random variable given by the minimum number of coefficients to change such that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: This was given as an oral exam , I think your approach is good , can you finish it ?

Comment: Are you a student from *classe préparatoire*? Is this an exercise from X-ENS competitive exam? If so, you should ask your professor. The exercises from this exam are really borderline and most of the time you are not supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: My teacher has no idea how to solve it , I'm getting stuck with it :)

Comment: This exercise was given in ens ulm 2016 , you're a student of ens ?

Comment: I am former student of *math sup/math spé*, but I am currently studying at the University Paris-Sud. Regarding, your problem I have no idea how to solve it, but since it is an exercise from X-ENS exam I think you are not supposed to find a solution. Maybe formalizing the statement as I did and solve it for law dimension $(n=1,2)$ when each entry follows independant  standard normal distributions is sufficient. The problem is voluntarily ill-asked.

Comment: Vous êtes abonné à la RMS Monsieur Falcon?

Comment: je cherche depuis longtemps le corrigé de l'épreuve de 6h maths ulm sevres 1981

Comment: Malheureusement non, je n'ai pas accès aux ressources de la RMS ! Ça m'arrangerait d'ailleurs !

Answer (score 2):

If you intend $R$ to be the real numbers $\bf R$, then an arbitrarily small perturbation to a singular matrix will result in a non-singular one.

Consider $A\in M_n({\bf R})$ singular, then $A$ has a Schur decomposition:

$$A=QUQ^{-1},$$

where $U$ is upper-triangular with diagonal containing the eigenvalues $\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n$ of $A$.

Let $0<\varepsilon < \displaystyle\min_{\lambda_i\neq 0}(|\lambda_i|)$, then we have:

$$A + \varepsilon I = QUQ^{-1} + \varepsilon I=Q(U + \varepsilon I)Q^{-1}.$$

This perturbation is now invertible since all its eigenvalues are non-zero, and we have:

$$\left\lVert \varepsilon I\right\rVert_2=\varepsilon.$$

*QED*

Geometrically every singular matrix corresponds to a point on the surface in eigenvalue space:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=0$$

in ${\bf C}^n.$

This surface has dimension $n-1$ over $\bf C$, and thus is of measure zero, so you should expect just from the geometry alone that arbitrarily small perturbations can result in a non-singular matrix.

Comment: Thank you for this extremely brilliant idea , but I still don't understand this part : Geometrically every singular matrix corresponds to a point on the surface in eigenvalue space:
$\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=0$
so what is the minimum of operations in changing coefficient ? thank you again sir

Comment: @Seginus The singular matrices are exactly those matrices with at least one zero eigenvalue, so all I was saying is that perturbing the matrix in the appropriate direction will cause the eigenvalues to perturb *off* this surface.  Think of a plane in ${\bf R}^3$, all you need to do is hover a tiny bit above it to leave it.  I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by "minimum of operations in changing the coefficient".

Comment: @Seginus, The part where I discuss the geometry is not part of the proof, I was simply trying to provide some intuition.

Comment: what I was trying to say is : what is the minimum of modifications of coefficents of the matric to make it invertible

Comment: @Seginus, what do you mean by "minimum"?  The definition of minimum I used with was the matrix 2-norm.

Comment: so I suppose from your proof that the answer is n ? because you changed all coefficient in the diagonal , ... but is that the minimum number of modifications to make the matrice nonsingular ?

Comment: @Seginus, the minimum number of elements you need to modify will depend on the matrix, for instance if you start with the zero matrix then you will need to modify more elements to make it non-singular than you would if you started with a diagonal matrix with only one zero diagonal element.

Comment: Thank you sir , It's me who didn't get the idea of the problem , I'am a student in preparatory classes so the idea of measure and surface isn't familiar to me , I hope you could give me more time to explain it or an article it will be so nice from :)